# How to delete accounts on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have been told that I have too many accounts on Stack Exchange. And he is right. Some are totally useless. Now I would like to delete those accounts. I have found the following advice:

[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Alas, this recipe does not work for me. Moreover I cannot post there because ... guess what ... I have no account there! Moreover, what is annoying, there seem to be other questions on the same issue, but they are all routed to the above one.

Can someone please explain me how I can delete some accounts?

Comment: I closed this question instead of migrating it to Meta SO. It is clearly off-topic here, but @MarcelC has strong opinions about migrating it to Meta SO.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: support questions are on-topic on any meta site. That's why there's a predefined [meta-tag:support] tag. Migrating these to MSO is a sure-fire way to dramatically increase support costs without actually resolving anything - please do not do this again.

Comment: That was my impression too. Meta is good for pretty much anything that does not for into the main site.

Comment: [At no point did I signal that you have too many accounts](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/1420/101) - you decided that. Heck, I have 35 :)

Comment: I decided that I have too many. And they are totally useless. Heck, can't you just respect this?

Comment: @MarcelC. I am in love with your attitude man..

Comment: @HaLaBi I am in love with your comments man..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that you've followed the instructions about changing your "about me" section to say "**please delete me**". The only other thing you need to do is to contact the SE team with links to all of the profiles you'd like deleted. Fill out the form on [this page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/contact/user-deletion) and include links to all of the accounts you want deleted.

That form will be sent to an email inbox that's checked by a real human being, so it may take a little while for someone to see and process your request. Filling out the form is a *request* for deletion, not deletion itself; one of the Stack Exchange community members will do the actual deletion.

Just a note, though: we have <strike>104</strike> [150+](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) sites in the SE network. You're certainly allowed to have accounts on as many sites as you wish. You don't *have* to delete them, though you're free to request deletion if you truly want it. I just want to make sure you know that we don't have an implicit or explicit rule limiting the number of sites you can participate in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. Your tone is pretty different from the pedantic and bossy comments I have received following my request. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Laura to clarify, [I certainly wasn't saying he had too many accounts](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/1420/101) - I was encouraging him to sign up for area51!  Wasn't expecting this :/

Comment: @MarkMayo Are you working as a beater for stackexchange?

Comment: Not at all, just want to clarify when someone changes my words around :)